# How to create an App Clip iOS 14 for an existing project

Tags: swift, ios14, apple-appclips

How do you add an App clip to an already existing project? I'm sure you will have to target iOS 14 and create some new files. But under `New file` There is nothing that suggests an app clip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to link this as the resources currently online are way to complicated.

All you need to do to add an app clip to your project:

File -> New -> Target -> Search "App clip" -> Create your app clip and select 'Yes' when it asks if you want to create the scheme.

I hope that helps anyone who had as much trouble with this as I did.

Comment: @matt That only further proves my point. Unless you watch the entire 2020WWDC videos, you won't get this. An app clip being a target is not obvious to people who are not expert iOS developers like yourself. This is a post for those who just want to look it up and get an answer, not a lecture.

Comment: OK so how about this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_an_app_clip_with_xcode "If you want to add an app clip to your existing iOS app..."